# Adding 1 to an integer value gives TypeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this is probably a super simple answer but I'm having some issues with a basic programming question.

I'm trying to program for python to add a specific variable in this case "age" + 1. It doesn't seem to be working

```
import cgi
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
text1 = form.getvalue("name")
text2 = int(form.getvalue("age"))
# print HTTP/HTML headers
print ("""Content-type: text/html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html><head>
<title>A CGI Script</title>
</head><body>
""")
print ("<p>Hello," +name+ ".</p>")
print ("<p>Next year you will be"  + str(age)+ 1 "years old</p>")
print ("</body></html>")
```

Comment: `print ("<p>Next year you will be", age + 1, "years old</p>")` is much clearer.

Comment: `print('<p>Next year you will be {} years old</p>'.format(age + 1))` is much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing "+" as string concatenation and variable incrementation.

It should be `str(age + 1)`.

```
age = 26
print ("This year I am " + str(age) + " years old.")
print ("Next year I will be " + str(age + 1) + " years old.")
```

Tested at http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python3_online.php

Comment: okay should my line look like this in that case "print ("<p>Next year you will be"  +str(age+1)+ "years old</p>")"

Comment: Python immediately shows "invalid syntax" when i run it, without showing me what the error is

Comment: Now i seem to be getting this error "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/JLau/Documents/CMPT 165/Lab 9/result.py", line 19, in <module>
    print ("Next year I will be " + str(age + 1) + " years old.")
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly" sorry for all the questions i'm pretty new at this so bear with me

Comment: Can you try putting exactly the code I wrote (nothing else) in your interpreter and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a +1 on the str in the example

```
print "Next year you will be  %s years old" % (int(age)+1)
```

Comment: Could you please show the syntax error and some code snippet please

Comment: `print` is a function in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
print ("Next year you will be " + str(age+1) + " years old.")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other problems with your code; there is a empty line missing after the `Content-Type` header; the code could use `str.format`, and variables were incorrectly named. Thus:

```
import cgi

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue("name")
age = int(form.getvalue("age"))
age_next_year = age + 1

content = """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>A CGI Script</title></head>
<body>
<p>Hello, {name}</p>
<p>Next year, you will be {age} years old</p>
</body>
</html>"""

formatted = content.format(name=name, age=age_next_year)
print(formatted)
```